# usage of lsetxattr and lgetxattr functions

Tags: c, linux, file, function

I wrote a simple program to test lsetxattr() and lgetxattr() functions.
I just wanted to add an extended property to this file, and get the value again.
But I can't get the result as expected.
So what's the right way to use these two methods?
Thanks!

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <ctype.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char *path = "/tmp/abc.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "w");

    int id = 101;
    if (lsetxattr(path, "user.id", &id, sizeof(int), 0) < 0)
        printf("lsetxattr wrong\n");

    int result;
    if (lgetxattr(path, "user.id", &result, sizeof(int)) != sizeof(int)) {
        printf("lgetxattr wrong\n");
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is one of your "wrong" messages printing, or is it just returning a result different from 101?

Comment: If the function returns -1, you should use `perror()` so that the reason is printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your `/tmp` mount does not support extended attributes. Looking at the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setxattr.2.html):

```
ENOTSUP
          Extended attributes are not supported by the file system, or are
          disabled, errno is set to ENOTSUP.
```

You can verify this by changing the path to be outside of that mount, such as in the current directory (assuming it's outside of that mount of course):

```
char *path = "abc.txt";
```

Assuming your other mounts do support extended attributes of course (this is more likely). If you have to do it on `/tmp`, then you'll have to look at some manuals to figure out how to enable it on `/tmp` (tmpfs).

Comment: Thanks. The /tmp does not support extended attributes. If I move the file to another mount, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both `lsetxattr()` and `lgetxatter()` return `-1` by default:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/xattr.h>

ssize_t
lgetxattr (const char *__path, const char *__name,
           void *__value, size_t __size)
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}

stub_warning (lgetxattr)
#include <stub-tag.h>
```

I found this on glibc's source code: [lgetxattr.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/generic/lgetxattr.c;h=6adf1fdf046d25d71b4383c64e12074e823602f6;hb=c0ad824e402c7afde1b46be1620c70107aa3eda9#l19) and [lsetxattr.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/lsetxattr.c;h=09e19cd0861a907327e63d71330a1cf4c5cb1bbb;hb=HEAD)